# What is the equivalent of this mad jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to convert some jQuery into vanilla JavaScript, but this one just stumped me:

```
$('<span>[<a href="#" id="addlink">Add</a>]</span>')
```

Comment: It's not a selector, it creates these elements and wrap it in a jQuery object.

Comment: You will have to use `document.createElement` then manually add `id` and `href`

Comment: I'm so glad the age of Jquery is coming to an end.

Comment: I do not think jQuery is going to die soon @captian kenpachi

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi I think it's a case of horses for courses. If you have a big app/site then jQuery is probably not a big overhead. However if you're making a small lean JavaScript app then it may be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a selector, it creates the DOM elements from this markup and wraps it in a jQuery object. [See the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

```js
const $el = $('<span>[<a href="#" id="addlink">Add</a>]</span>');
console.log( $el.html() );
$("body").append( $el );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So the vanilla equivalent would be

```js
const span = document.createElement("span");
const a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "#";
a.id = "addlink";
a.textContent = "Add";
span.append( "[", a, "]" );

document.body.append( span );
```

Answer (score 0):

The Vanilla Javascript approach for the same could also be achieved using `setAttribute()` , `createTextNode()` and `appendChild()` as follows. Just another way to do this.

```js
const span = document.createElement("span");
const a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute("href", "#");
a.setAttribute("id", "addlink");

const text = document.createTextNode("Add");

a.appendChild(text);
span.append("[", a, "]");

document.body.appendChild(span);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For what advantages?

Comment: Advantages !!!  Just another way to do it using vanilla javascript making use of more Vanilla javascript specific function ;) Nothing much.